# Recover from Rails JSON ParserError Caused by Tabs

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to recover from JSON with illegal characters (like tabs).  Would it be reasonable to simply escape the tabs on failure?

Please advise:

```rb
module ActiveSupport
  module JSON
    class <<self
      alias_method :alias_for_decode, :decode
    end

    def self.decode(raw_post)
      self.alias_for_decode(raw_post)
    rescue ::JSON::ParserError => ex
      escaped_tabs = raw_post.gsub("\t", "\\t")
      self.alias_for_decode(escaped_tabs)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "Reasonable" is hugely subjective here. "Necessary" is a lot easier to determine. Can you get the upstream source to fix their non-standard output?

Comment: Possibly, but even getting them reasonable feedback may require a monkey patch also.  My preference was to create a new JSON parser similar to above, and configure ActiveSupport Action Dispatch to use it (Instead of monkey patching like above) ... another alternative may be middleware.

Comment: Middleware is most likely a better alternative. Thoughbot [has a guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware) but it's pretty dated. I think the exception raised in modern versions of Rails is [ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters/ParseError.html).

Comment: Although the context here is somewhat important. Are you making requests from your server and getting a bad response or are they sending requests  to your server with broken JSON?

Comment: The later, I'm receiving bad requests.

Comment: I've fixed up things like this, addressing invalid UTF-8, using a simple Rack handler that looks for JSON submissions and "fixes" them if necessary. Might be worth doing the same here instead of patching the JSON decoder itself.